# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow

**I was battling this issue for the last 6 hours, so I decided to post a question and answer my own question, in case anyone else has this same issue.**

Why does the following line:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

cause the following errors?

```
The directory '/Users/ruchirbaronia/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

and

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
```

I have tried upgrading Tensorflow, reinstalling pip, my version of python is 3.6 (which is supported), and even reinstalled tensorflow with `pip install --upgrade  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-py2-none-any.whl` using multiple versions from the **official** link from google. Why is midi-rnn still not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The preceding line was the cause of over 9000 frantic google searches and resulted in the following two errors depending on whether I did/didn't use sudo (respectively):

```
The directory '/Users/ruchirbaronia/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

and

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
```

Although these errors were verbose, they were not descriptive enough to allow me to pinpoint my issue. It turned out, the reason `midi-rnn` was not working was that the version of python (3.6) was clashing with the version of tensor flow (1.0.1). So how did I fix it?

**You can create and activate a new environment with python version 3.5 by doing `conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5`**

This creates a new python enviornment using version 3.5. After doing so, installing requirements.txt was a piece of cake, and I was able to start training my neural network!

Comment: Um... So if I understand you well, you asked a question you have solved and posted the solution you found as an answer. But what I really want to say, this whole thing is... just a piece of a piece of cake. Anyway, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: BTW, the first issue is caused by directories' owner is not current user, you can solve this problem just by `sudo chown -R ruchirbaronia:ruchirbaronia /Users/ruchirbaronia/Library`

Comment: The `Library` directory on MacOS is basically a system resource. Changing the owner is definitely fine but recursively changing owner *and group* is something I would hesitate to recommend without further proof that you really know that this is okay.